# access query error

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm getting a syntax error with this access query, but I can't see what it is.

> Error: The SELECT statment includes a reserved word or an argument
>   name that is misspelled or missing, or the puntuation is incorrect.

Query:

```
 SELECT W.[skid number]             AS SkidNum,
       W.job                       AS JobNum,
       W.[job skid number]         AS JobSkidNum,
       W.form                      AS Form,
       W.DATE                      AS DATE,
       W.shift                     AS Shift,
       W.[team member number]      AS Operator,
       W.[roll tender number]      AS Helper,
       W.weight                    AS Weight,
       W. lbs                      AS Pounds,
       ( W.weight / W.lbs ) * 1000 AS Sheets,
       W.press                     AS Press
FROM   [press 1a skid entry] W
UNION ALL
SELECT SF.[skid number]        AS SkidNum,
       SF.job                  AS JobNum,
       SF.[job skid number]    AS JobSkidNum,
       SF.form                 AS Form,
       SF.DATE                 AS DATE,
       SF.shift                AS Shift,
       SF.[team member number] AS Operator,
       SF.[roll tender number] AS Helper,
       ""                      AS Weight,
       ""                      AS Pounds,
       SF.[total sheets]       AS Sheets,
       SF.press                AS Press
FROM   [sheet fed 1a skid entry] SF;
```

Comment: Form is also a reserved word.  Examine your database with Allen Browne's Database Issue Checker Utility: http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueChecker.html

Comment: @HansUp - Form isn't causing problems in this case, but great link!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a column called `DATE` and this is a [reserved word in MS Access](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286335).

If you want to use `DATE` then place brackets around it `[DATE]`

Answer (score 3):

You used the word Date, thats a reserved word.

you can view the list of reserved words [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286335)

Comment: +1 for the list.  I was wondering if *weight* was a reserved word (it is in MS SQL), but apparently not.